# Meaning of max segments queue param linux

Tags: kernel

What is meaning of value stored in /sys/block/sda/queue/max_segments (what are those segments?) ? Is it fixed value assigned to block device? Or can I change it in runtime? Where in kernel this value is set initially? Considering scsi and nvme, is it set in different places? Is it matter of driver?

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se]!  **;-)** We're sorry but we're not a forum but a Question&Answer site: It works best if you ask *one question*, so you can receive *one answer*.  When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas which becomes more unlikely the more questions you put into... well, one question!  **;-)** So I've answered one of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Linux Kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/queue-sysfs.txt):

> ### max_integrity_segments (RO)
>
> When read, this file shows the max limit of integrity segments as
>   set by block layer which a hardware controller can handle.

and a bit lower:

> ### max_segments (RO)
>
> Maximum number of segments of the device.

Both are Read-Only values set by the hardware of the block device and can change per device but no, you cannot change them at run time.